# Removal of first characters in a string oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

It may be very simple question, but I have run out of ideas.
I would like to remove first 5 characters from string.

Example string will look like:
1Y40K100R

I would like to display only digits that are after '%K' which in this case should give me result of 100R. 
Please note that number after 'K' can have different amount of digits. It can be 4 digit number or 2 digit number.

Comment: You are contradicting yourself is such a short space - this must be a record! Do you want to remove the first five characters regardless of what they are, or do you want to remove everything up to and including K? (If there is more than one K, **which** K? The first one? the last one?) Or is the fifth character always K, and you must remove the first five characters in call cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `substr()`:

```
select substr(col, 6)
```

This returns all characters starting at the sixth.

There are multiple ways to return all characters after the `k`.  If you know the string has a `k`, then use `instr()`:

```
select substr(col, instr(col, 'K') + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`regexp_substr`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/REGEXP_SUBSTR.html#GUID-2903904D-455F-4839-A8B2-1731EF4BD099)

```
select regexp_substr('1Y40K100R', '(K)(.*)', 1, 1, 'i', 2) from dual
```

A way without regexp:

```
select substr('1Y40K100R', instr('1Y40K100R', 'K') +1) from dual
```

This may appear not so elegant, but it usually performs better than the regexp way.